# SQL Server Datatypes for DB2/AS400 Decimals with byte length and Decimal Length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to load data from a AS400 DB2 system to **SQL Server 2012**. The extracted data is in a excel format from which I need to load to SQL Server. Referred [IBM DB2/AS400 Subscribers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237110%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

I have following decimal types in DB2/AS400.

1. Byte Length = 2, Decimal Length =3, Dec Pos = 0
2. Byte Length = 3, Decimal Length =5, Dec Pos = 2
3. Byte Length = 3, Decimal Length =3, Dec Pos = 0
4. Byte Length = 3, Decimal Length =5, Dec Pos = 4
5. Byte Length = 4, Decimal Length =4, Dec Pos = 0
6. Byte Length = 4, Decimal Length =6, Dec Pos = 3
7. Byte Length = 4, Decimal Length =7, Dec Pos = 4
8. Byte Length = 5, Decimal Length =5, Dec Pos = 0
9. Byte Length = 5, Decimal Length =9, Dec Pos = 4
10. Byte Length = 6, Decimal Length =11, Dec Pos = 0
11. Byte Length = 6, Decimal Length =11, Dec Pos = 2
12. Byte Length = 6, Decimal Length =11, Dec Pos = 4
13. Byte Length = 6, Decimal Length =11, Dec Pos = 5
14. Byte Length = 7, Decimal Length =13, Dec Pos = 4
15. Byte Length = 7, Decimal Length =7, Dec Pos = 2
16. Byte Length = 9, Decimal Length = 9, Dec Pos = 4

What is the corresponding datatype in SQL Server 2012 for each of these?

What is the rationale behind selecting these datatypes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you don't get to define how much storage a `decimal` takes up - SQL Server has fixed storage requirements. So I think we have to ignore the Byte Length, if I'm interpreting that as a storage size requirement. As to the rest, in SQL Server, you declare [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) as:

```
decimal (p ,s)
```

Where `p` is the precision (total number of digits in all parts of the number), and `s` is the scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point).

Since all of the types you've shown have a larger "decimal length" that "Dec Pos", I'm going to assume that these concepts map across directly to `decimal`s precision and scale.

So type number 1 would be `decimal(3,0)` and number 16 would be `decimal(9,4)`.

Comment: Can't we use `money` as datatype? Note: When excel loaded the data, it loaded as `float` in SQL Server

Comment: @Lijo - you can but I wouldn't recommend it. It's **like** a `decimal(19,4)` except it has some weird rounding rules.